# 'Residentship' and 'Citizenship'

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Is it correct to use:
`Residentship` to indicate the country I am currently living in ?
`Citizenship` to indicate the country where I was born ?

I am using these words in my CV:

> - Residentship: Germany  (or German ?)
> - Citizenship:  France   (or French ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more common formal term for where you live now would be **[residency](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/residency)**.  Your residency would be "Germany".

*[Citizenship](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/citizenship)* is a common term on forms, but it means "what country do you hold citizenship in", not literally "where you were born" - usually, you are a citizen of the country you were born in, but there are many people who were born in one country, but are legally citizens of another country.  (For example, the US politician John McCain was born within the country of Panama, but he is legally a citizen of the US.)  Your *citzenship* might be "French".

Answer (score -3):

-Yes, I think so. Residentship refer to a person who resides in a place. Citizenship is the country you were born.

Comment: "Residentship" is almost unheard of.  Yes, technically it means "the state of being a resident", but I have never seen it used in my life.